# While loop with an "OR" condition

Tags: perl

Below is a code snippet that asks for user input, and if the input is not either "csv" or "newline", the while loop is called.

For line 5, what is the correct syntax for the while loop where it attempts to match `$format` to either "csv" or "newline"? Currently it is only seems to be matching "csv".

```
1 # Request output format
2 print "Format of email addresses required (csv|newline): ";
3 $format = <>;
4 chop($format);
5 while ($format ne ("csv"||"newline")) {
6   print "Invalid format. Enter in csv or newline: ";
7   $format = <>;
8   chop($format);
9 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while ($format ne 'csv' && $format ne 'newline') {
    ...
}
```

or

```
while ($format !~ /^(csv|newline)$/) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If using Perl >= `v5.10`, the closest working example to what you tried is:

```
while ( not $format ~~ ["csv", "newline"] ) {
```

Otherwise, both of [rob mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8290515/91768)'s solutions will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (($format ne "csv") && ($format ne "newline))
```

Since `||` is a short-circuiting operator, the expression `("csv" || "newline)` returns "csv" because csv is doesn't evaluate to false, so its returned first. If it was `("newline" || "csv")`, it would have returned newline (I believe).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `while (($format ne "csv") && ($format ne "newline")) { }`.

In your code, the result of `"csv"||"newline"` is `"cvs"`; your code is then equivalent to `while ($format ne "csv") { }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
($format ne "csv" && $format ne "newline")...
```